# Module '"tsparticles-engine"' has no exported member 'loadFull'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a particles animation that appears in the background of an html page using

```
npm install ng-particles tsparticles-engine
```

I am using angular 15. I keep getting the error Module '"tsparticles-engine"' has no exported member 'loadFull'

I am trying to put a background particles animation and but angular says it cant find it. This is a link to the library that I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-particles

Comment: @Vikas thank you so much , it is working splendidly :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `loadFull` you must install `tsparticles`, it's not mandatory since you can use loadSlim from `tsparticles-slim` or any other preset, or custom configuration including manually the plugins you prefer.

`npm i tsparticles`

[`See Issue Link`](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/issues/4784)
[`Working StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x3pikj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)